# write unit test request->ajax() laravel

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

how to write test for this function ??
how to test request-ajax()??

```
public function getChangeLoc(Request $request, $loc)
{   
    if ($request->ajax()) {

        if(!in_array($loc, config('loc.available'))) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'ERROR',
                'message' => 'Not available'
            ]);
        }
        Session::put('locale', $loc);

        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'OK',
            'loc' => $loc,
        ]);
    }

    if(!in_array($loc, config('loc.available'))) {
        return Redirect::to('/?unknown-loc);
    }
    Session::put('loc', $loc);

    if(filter_var($request->input('redirect_url', ''), FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
        return Redirect::to($request->input('redirect_url'));
    }

    return Redirect::to('/');
}
```

I test the function like this

```
            $this->visit('/loc/en')
                 ->seePageIs('/admin/client')
```

but its not see request->ajax?

Answer (score 2):

To test ajax requests you can implement function in your TestCase class this method. Your request needs HTTP_X-Requested-With header.

```
protected function ajaxPost($route = '', array $parameters = [])
{
    return empty($route) ? null : $this->json(
        'post',
        $route,
        $parameters,
        ['HTTP_X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest']
    );
}
```

Now you can test your classes

```
$this->ajaxPost(route('your.route'), ['foo' => 'bar'])->seeJson([
    'is_ok' => true,
]);
```

Remember: it's not unit tests.

Comment: the route method is get so it will be get not post right ?

Comment: And what have to fill inside $route = ' '  and  inside parameters = [ ] ??

Comment: Yes, route in this method is POST target. Parameters are optional - look at the example. :)

Comment: OK this is what i did in TestCase 
    protected function ajaxGet($route = '', array $parameters = [])
    {
        return empty($route) ? null : $this->json(
            'get',
            $route,
            $parameters,
            ['HTTP_X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest']
        );
    }
what to fill also??